# Why is $(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n>3^n(n!)^2$

Tags: inequality, factorial

> Why is $(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n>3^n(n!)^2$ for $n>1$

I can use $$(n+1)^n>(2n)!!=n!2^n$$ but in the my case, the exponent is always decreased by $1$, for the moment I don't care about it, I apply the same for $n+2$

$(n+2)^{n+1}>(2n+2)!!=(n+1)!2^{n+1}$

gathering everything together,

$(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n=\frac{(n+1)^n(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}>\frac{(n+1)(n!)^22^{2n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

$\iff(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n>(n!)^2\times\frac{2^{2n+1}}{(n+2)}$

but $\frac{2^{2n+1}}{(n+2)}>3^n$ is not true for $n=2$

can you suggest another approach ?

Comment: If the desired inequality is true for $n$ sufficiently large, then prove the remaining (finite) cases directly.

Comment: $\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n+2}=\frac{2}{n+2}4^n$ and that is greater than $3^n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so you can check your original inequality for all lower cases (shouldn't be many).

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's what I wanted to avoid. I want a general formula without excluding bad cases

Comment: Why?  If you're just trying to prove it, that would work.  What application do you have in mind that would require a single uniform proof?

Comment: In fact your final inequality holds true for $n>3$. So exactly two cases are to be checked manually. Seems the way to go.

Comment: @Macavity Yes it seems there's no alternative to it, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say no alternative, but you already have a perfectly valid proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Induction for the step $n+1$:

$$(n+2)^{n}(n+3)^{n+1}=\frac{(n+3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n-1}}(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^{n}>3^n(n!)^2\frac{(n+3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n-1}}$$

We may expect

$$\frac{(n+3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n-1}}>3(n+1)^2 \quad (1)$$

in order to finish the induction.

Backing to $(1)$ we have an equivalent expression:

$$\left(\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}>3 \Leftrightarrow \left(1+\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}>3$$

Using the Bernoulli inequality $(1+x)^m \ge1+mx$ for $x>-1$.

Taking $m=n+1$ and $x=\frac{2}{n+1}$ we get what we want.

Answer (score 2):

prove: $(n+1)^{n−1}(n+2)^n>3^n(n!)^2=3^n(n!n!)$ for $n>1$

$n=2:3^14^2=48>3^2(2)(2)=36$

assume: $(n+1)^{n−1}(n+2)^n>3^n(n!n!)$

need to arrive at: $(n+2)^{n}(n+3)^{n+1}>3^{n+1}(n+1)!(n+1)!$

for lhs need to multiply by: 
${{(n+2)^{n}(n+3)^{n+1}}\over {(n+1)^{n−1}(n+2)^n}}
={{(n+3)^n(n+3)(n+1)}\over {(n+1)^n}}=({{n+3}\over {n+1}})^n(n+3)(n+1)$

where $({{n+3}\over {n+1}})^n$ is greater than $3$ for $n=3$ and increasing for all $n\in N$.

for rhs need to multiply by: $3(n+1)(n+1)$.  therefore lhs > rhs and

$(n+1)^{n−1}(n+2)^n>3^n(n!)^2$ for $n>1$ by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if
something simple works.

You want
$(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n
>3^n(n!)^2
$.

First,
$(n+1)^{n-1}(n+2)^n
> n^{2n-1}
$.

Second,
since
$(n/e)^n < n! < (n/e)^{n+1}
$
(easily proved by induction from
$(1+1/n)^n < e < (1+1/n)^{n+1}$),
$3^n (n!)^2
< 3^n(n/e)^{n+1}
= (3n/e)^n(n/e)
$.

Therefore,
if
$n^{2n-1}
> (3n/e)^n(n/e)
$,
we are done.

This is the same as
$(ne/3)^n > n^2/e
$
or
$ne/3 
> (n^2/e)^{1/n}
= (n^{1/n})^2/e^{1/n}
$.

But
$n^{1/n}
< e^{1/e}
<1.5
$
and
$e^{1/n} > 1$
so
$(n^{1/n})^2/e^{1/n}
< 1.5^2
= 2.25
$.

Therefore
$ne/3 
> (n^{1/n})^2/e^{1/n}
$
if
$ne/3 > 2.25$
or
$n > 3\cdot 2.25/ e
\approx 2.48
$.

Smaller $n$ easily verified.

---

Someone commented "How do you know that
$e^{1/e} < 1.5$?". My answer was "Calculator."

Here is a calculator-free answer.

But
$n^{1/n}
< e^{1/e}
< \sqrt{3}
$
(since
$2 <e < 3$)
and
$e^{1/n} > 1$
so
$(n^{1/n})^2/e^{1/n}
< (\sqrt{3})^2
= 3
$.

Therefore
$ne/3 
> (n^{1/n})^2/e^{1/n}
$
if
$ne/3 > 3$
or
$n > 3\cdot 3/ e
= 9/e
\approx 3.31
$.

Smaller $n$ easily verified.

Comment: how do you know that $e^{1/e}<1.5$ ?

Comment: Calculator. Even Google says it is 1.44466786. Approximately, of course.

Comment: @user257: I added a calculator-free estimate which is almost as good.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is wrong, because I mixed up my left and right-hand sides right at the end. I think it is salvageable, but it'll be quite a bit of work.

I'll do it without induction.

Rearrange: we want $\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3}\right)^{n-1} \frac{n+2}{3} > (n!)^2$

We'll show that this actually holds if we remove the $\frac{n+2}{3}$ term (which is always $\geq 1$ anyway).

The right-hand side of the modified desired inequality is is $$2^2 \times 3^2 \times \dots \times n^2$$ with $n-1$ terms.
The left-hand side is $$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3} \times \dots \times \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$ with $n-1$ terms again.
But $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$ is bigger than or equal to the $i^2$ term whenever $i$ is less than or equal to $\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3}}$, and that's $\leq n$ whenever $n > 2$. So if $n>2$, for every $i \leq n$ we have each right-hand term less than its corresponding left-hand term.

So we only need to check $n=1$ and $n=2$, and they're very easy.

Comment: ''...and that's $\leq n$ whenever $n > 2$...'' are you sure ? for example Is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3}>(n-1)^2$ if $n=5$

Comment: I think I'm sure… you're right that $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3} > (n-1)^2$ at $n=5$, but I only said "$\sqrt{\cdot} \leq n$", not "$\sqrt{\cdot} < n$".

Comment: Then I don't understand your conclusion, so let $n=5$ then; $\frac{(5+1)(5+2)}{3}=14\color{red}{<}16=(5-1)^2$ or even $\frac{(5+1)(5+2)}{3}=14\color{red}{<}25=5^2$ , so we don't have each right hand- term less than its corresponding left-hand term

Comment: @user257 My bad, I'm sorry. I got my left and right mixed up. I think this answer is salvageable, but it will take some work to find the bound.